# How to make a column of a table a hyperlink in python?

Tags: python, html

Im building an alert system for my work that will automatically email out a table with data to the recipient. I iterate through the data of a SQL statement to fill a HTML table I've built. Everything works as is, however I would like the data of the first column to be a clickable hyperlink. Im not sure how to build the html in python, I need each cell in the row to be its own unique hyperlink.

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3NIL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the second loop by adding this line:

```
for row in alertq:
    htmlString = htmlString + '<tr>'

    row[0] = f'<a href="{str(row[0]).strip()}">url</a>' # add this

    for col in row:
        htmlString = htmlString + '<td>' + str(col).strip() + '</td>'

    htmlString = htmlString + '</tr>'
```

I'm not a python pro, but it should work.

In this line I take what's in the first column, bring it to a string like each column, then wrap the content (as I understood from your words it should be a link) in a tag *a*, assigning the content of the first column (the link itself) to the a attribute of the tag *a* - href.

What I've specified inside the *a* tag itself (in this case text "url") will appear as active text so that when a user clicks on it they will follow the link specified in the href attribute.

You can specify any text inside a tag *a*, either as a single text for all columns or you can include it dynamically by setting a variable, wrapping it in curly braces as I did in the example.